# how to get all parameters for a specific application

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-reporting-api

I have the below query

```
data_query = service.customerUsageReports().get(**{'date':'2015-01-07','parameters':'gmail:num_outbound_rerouted_emails'})
```

What I'm wondering is how to just receive all the gmail specific parameters without listing each one out individually....

This is the adminSDK reports API...

Thanks

Comment: I think the only way to get all the parameters is to specify in the parameter query string as comma separated list in Reports API.

Comment: That is what I'm seeing. I was just hoping for a application specific way. There are a lot of reporting returned...just need about 20 so it is a lot to comma delimit. Since I'm going to have to deal with Oracle databases anyway I'm just grabbing everything formatting the data and inserting the whole thing into the database. Letting peopel choose what they want to reporting on.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible.